# How to make rounded corners in DrawerLayout straight when switching to Theme.Material3

Tags: android, material-components-android, drawerlayout, android-navigationview, material3

I've started the default Android project, "Navigation Drawer Activity".

[image]

I've changed the theme to:

```
<!-- <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">-->
    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

But then the Drawer has rounded corners:

[image]

How can I make these corners straight again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corner size of the `NavigationView` is defined by the **`drawerLayoutCornerSize`** attribute in the style (default value with **M3** theme = `16dp`).

You can use in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:drawerLayoutCornerSize="0dp"
```

or you can define a custom style:

```
<style name="App.Material3.NavigationView" parent="Widget.Material3.NavigationView">
    <item name="drawerLayoutCornerSize">0dp</item>
</style>
```

and then apply it to the `NavigationView`

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    style="@style/App.Material3.NavigationView"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in the `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView`

```
app:drawerLayoutCornerSize="0dp"
```